# Quarkus based aws lambda fails frequently with permission error

Tags: aws-lambda, quarkus

We are facing a problem with quarkus based aws lambda (native image). It fails every now and then while running with following error.

```
Error: fork/exec /var/task/bootstrap: permission denied
Runtime.
```

Sometimes it recovers itself and sometime we have to redeploy the lambda. It also breaks sometimes during redeployment. This is a mission critical lambda and is called several times per minute.

Just like a standard quarkus lambda, it generates a zip file in target directory `function.zip` contain three file `bootstrap`, `bootstrap.sh` and `cacerts`.
According to this (https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-deployment-package-errors) lambda files should have permission 644. So I tried to update the lambda permission 644 (and also tried 664) in my buid script but problem remains

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true

echo "updating permissions"
cd target
unzip function.zip
chmod 644 bootstrap bootstrap.sh cacerts
rm function.zip
zip -rm function.zip bootstrap bootstrap.sh cacerts

echo "Build Completed"
cd ..
```

I am using Quarkus v3.1.0.Final with Java 11 and building using container. I tried building in on Ubuntu 23.04 and also from aws codebuild (aws/codebuild/standard:5.0) but nothing worked. (We had same issue with Quarkus 2.x so even upgrade didn't resolve it)

There are two question mainly.

- What is causing the issue?
- How to fix this?

Any help is appreciated.